# Angular project doesn't redirect to index.html

Tags: angular

I have built angular project and run it. But localhost doesn't redirect to index.html automatically, I have to manually type localhost:8080/index.html. How can I solve that issue?
I have this problem on Windows (angular version is 8), but on Linux and Mac everything work ok.

I have tried change the base href and even delete it, since I found this advice from stackoverflow.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PsAir</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
 </head>
```

App-routing file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: routesNames.AUTH,
    loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { checkAuth: true }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '../index.html',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you show your ``index.html`` file

Comment: Have you tried generating a fresh project using angular-cli and check the differences? I've recently did this with angular-cli and it worked perfectly on windows for me. Also make sure you have the correct version of node installed.

Comment: What webserver do you use?

Comment: @Abdulrahman
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PsAir</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

Comment: @David http-server

Comment: Have your created your project using angular-cli?

Comment: Please try 
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
``ng build --base-href /myUrl/``

Comment: @Ms.Tamil yes, I have

Comment: @Abdulrahman I have tried ng build --base-href ./
Did not help

Comment: Might be a silly question. Do you have your root elt in index.html? and defined default route in routes file?

Comment: @Ms.Tamil app-routing file:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: routesNames.AUTH,
    loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { checkAuth: true }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '../index.html',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

Comment: So what page/error do you get when you navigate to `http://localhost:8080` ? And which command do you use to run the server?

Comment: Please update your question and add body of your index.html too

Comment: @David npm install -g http-server. Then http-server. 404 error

Comment: You also need to specify the dist folder `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist`

Comment: @David the port is given and command run in dist folder

Comment: @SamanthaAdrichem I've created the simple angular application on windows and this application also requires to type manually localhost:8080/index.html
However, after getting the page 'index.html' disappears but still getting error when trying to enter just 'localhost:8080'

Answer (score 0):

Using angular-http-server instead of http-server solved the problem.

> It returns a file if it exists (ex. your-icon.png, index.html), routes all other requests to index.html (rather than giving a 404 error) so that you SPA's routing can take over. The only time it will error out is if it can't locate the index.html file.
>   [Read more about angular-http-server here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server)